# Webview open wrong url

Tags: android, webview

I have activity with `WebView`. I open in webview specific url:

> https://example.com/page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813

I'm use own `WebViewClient` for `WebView`. I add logging in WebViewClient (onPageStarted). So, `url` parameter really have: https://example.com/page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813

Some more code:

```
if (EnvUtils.isLollipop()) {
            webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        }

        with(webView.settings) {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true

        }
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813")
```

I test this code on different devices.
Typically, I have in access log of `ngingx`:

> GET /page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813
>   HTTP/1.0" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; D5803
>   Build/23.5.A.1.291; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/4.0 Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36" 395

Server redirect to new page (302). It's normal.

But one device (Sony Xperia M4) working strange. I have in access log:

> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 15086
>   "https://example.com/page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; E2333 Build/26.3.B.1.33; wv)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0

Why works wrong on Sony?

Comment: `GET /favicon.ico` What is wrong on the Sony's WebView requesting a favicon?

Comment: @greenapps I want, that on Sony device will opened by `https://example.com/page?param1=hash=0da985c97d7629ce0bcae375462880f6&param2=72813` like on other devices.

Comment: Yes i know. And it will open the page and the favicon normally. You did not tellthat it did not open both. And has anything to do with redjrecting? What is dissplayed by the webview?

Comment: I'm use specific case. I open url in webview and then page loaded, I quickly hide webview and show new UI. I'm afraid, that I did it on onPageStarted. May be I should do it on onPageFinished?